# ios native app talking to an API or direct database connections?

Tags: ios, node.js, api

Folks,
  Designing an ios application, and would like to confirm my strategy.  There is a database (dynamo/mongo/etc) i am building up, which the app needs to make use of.  Is it smart to front the database with an API, and have the ios app authenticate against the api.
  This way the app makes calls to the api instead of directly to the database?

Would you suggest node.js be a good place to start crafting the web api with?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, access the  data via an API. Whether fancy authentication is needed, depends on what is stored in your database, and what your application is designed to do. Here is one resource (among millions) on API design: http://www.vinaysahni.com/best-practices-for-a-pragmatic-restful-api

Also, here is a popular networking library for iOS: https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking

As for what technology to use, that too open ended and you will get 10 answers for every technology available. This should help though: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/154519/44948